# What is the difference between political liberalism and comprehensive liberalism?

Tags: ethics, politics

I have seen many discussions of this difference but not one reference defines either or the difference between the two. I am working through Will Kymlicka’s (2002) Contemporary Political Philosophy (2nd ed.) but even he does not give concise definitions of these terms.

Answer (score 0):

Both terms are poorly defined, but the essence of the difference between is that political liberalism is a view in favour of a state that interferes minimally with the freedoms of individuals and groups, whereas comprehensive liberalism has a broader purview. Political liberalism is mainly concerned with what should and shouldn't be the role of the state, whereas comprehensive liberalism would also be concerned with the roles of individuals, groups, businesses, etc etc etc. That all said, you'll find wide variations in the use of the terms, so you have to make allowances for the context.